# How do I create pretty urls on non-index pages?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm sorry for making you guys spin your heads off for me.
This is my situation:
In my **htdocs** folder, I have a folder called **mediaschedulesgh**.
In mediaschedulesgh, I have all the web files. so, it is my root folder. the **index.php**, **ghana-radio-stations.php** and **.htaccess** are in mediaschedulesgh with other folders.
What I want to achieve is to rewrite 
`^ghana-radio-stations\/([^/]*)$` internally to

```
ghana-radio-stations.php?region=$1 [L]
```

this is the rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ghana-radio-stations\/([^/]*)$ ghana-radio-stations.php?region=$1 [L]
```

I want this url `ghana-radio-stations/ashanti`to map to `ghana-radio-stations.php?region=ashanti`

But this gives **page not found** error.

Comment: does the file ghana-radio-stations.php exist?
Why you don't like `RewriteRule ^ghana-radio-stations\/([^/]*)$ index.php?region=$1 [L]` ?

Comment: yes, the files exist.

Comment: so what is not working? Show what you have tried so far...

Comment: I want to run http://localhost:81/my_projects/mediaschedulesgh/ghana-radio-stations.php?region=ashanti when i click on http://localhost:81/my_projects/mediaschedulesgh/ghana-radio-stations/ashanti

Comment: my index.php, ghana-radio-stations.php and .htaccess files are in the root directory

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do

There is not a single line of code on your question. we cannot guess what you are doing or trying to do in your php file

Comment: Is your .htaccess in `my_projects/mediaschedulesgh/` directory?

Comment: yes, my .htaccess in my_projects/mediaschedulesgh/ directory.

Comment: Do you have `my_projects/mediaschedulesgh` defined as [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) in your server or virtual host configuration?

Comment: I'm running apache server on my pc. I created a folder called **my_projects** in htdocs. In **my_projects**, I have several folders each with a different project. one of these project folders is **mediaschedulesgh.** I guess this makes mediaschedulesgh a DocumentRoot. @Olaf Dietsche, hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) is a directive in your Apache configuration. In your case it seems to be `htdocs`.

Comment: I just tried your .htaccess in my test environment and it works as it should.